# Mac OSX fullscreen application problem

Tags: cocoa, macos, sdl, fullscreen

My application uses **SDL** library.
For enter to fullscreen mode I use **SDL_SetVideoMode** and appropriate flag - **SDL_FULLSCREEN**.

Problem:
When application is in fullscreen mode, I can't call **"force quit" dialog** and **switching** between other applications.
After **Cmd+Option+ESQ** clicking my application is quit instead of **"force quit" dialog** is appear. And on **Cmd+Tab** clicking nothing is happens...

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

As says on another forum:

**"That is the normal behavior for the APIs that SDL is using.
10.5 added a new API (-[NSView enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:]
which has slightly different behavior, I think, but SDL is not using it."**

So, maybe someone knows any possibilities to achieve this behavior in application based on SDL library?

Answer (score 0):

SDL is not the best choice for Mac OS X I think, native API like Cocoa give you full easy  control than one